# got error on datetime while using JsonServices in asp.net and android

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, json

We are doing an app which uses jsonservice(webservice/RESTfull webservice) for backend datadase proccess and andriod as front end..

```
public DataTable retrv(string id)
{
    check();
    int ID = Convert.ToInt32(id.ToString());
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText = "select * from RECVSSMS where Refid='" + ID + "'";
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);         
    return dt;
}
```

While using this code using jsonservice from Android Studio we got all the records in exact format except the Date_Time.

we got records like this :

> I/System.out: @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@{"Value":[{"Date_time":"2016-04-22T02:01:15","status":"1","Message":"test messag reply automatic","FromID":"+919566003138","Refid":24}],"Successful":true}

here is the error clearly : `Date_time":"2016-04-22T02:01:15"`

An alphabet 'T' appears and incorrect date format

This is database fields:

```
Refid int 
FromID varchar(13)
Message varchar(60)
status varchar(5)
Date_Time datetime
```

Answer (score -1):

It's not an error it's one of the date time formats sql provide please use the below formatting code to get the desired date

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp

Comment: but I just tested with a gridview in asp.net webform..it displays the correct format... but when use the webservice form  the android studio it changes the format,,

Comment: @Abdu .Net can understand sql dates, when you convert to json you should convert it to either json date format /\date() or the way you want it